# Http502 error in Node component(code is for reference only.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, chatbot

Hi I am getting `Http502` error while designing node component for chatbot. first code is working perfectly but second one is giving http502 error. you need not to read all the `code`. it is just for referecne. I am using same `host and same proxy setting` for both, only end point is change.still second is not working. What I am missing? Simple `NODE API call` is working for both. error is coming when I am designing component.

am I hadnling proxy issue properly? is it proper way?

```
   'use strict';
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
var request = require('request');
var username = "shrutisharma@infy.com";
var password = 'Password';
var baseUrl = 'https://xxxxx18993c046e585b90bc8cc5e1f80-jcs.oci.cloudonline.ml:443';
var baseUrlwoHttps = baseUrl.substring(8);
process.env["NO_PROXY"] = baseUrlwoHttps;
var getUrl = baseUrl + '/IMCMCSREST/rest/v1/PlannedCosts';
var outcome;
var options = {
    url: getUrl,
    auth: {
        user: username,
        password: password
    }
}
```

Below one is not working

```
'use strict';
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
var request = require('request')
var username = "shrutisharma@infy.com";
var password = 'DDixit90';
var baseUrl = 'https://xxxxx18993c046e585b90bc8cc5e1f80-jcs.oci.cloudonline.ml:443';
var baseUrlwoHttps = baseUrl.substring(8);
process.env["NO_PROXY"] = baseUrlwoHttps;
var getUrl = baseUrl + '/IMCMCSREST/rest/v1/PlannedCosts/2007/child/CmiCpPlanCostTypesView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child/CstCostTypesView/5000003046/child/CstItemCostsView';
var options = {
    url: getUrl,
    auth: {
        user: username,
        password: password
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there is no issue. To understand more please put the entire code.
One think I would suggest here there can be some undeclared variable or any sort of compilation issue because of which your chatbot is not able to communicate with server. you have use `use strict` so even undeclared variable will give error. proxy server issue is not there if it is working for one component.